# How to bind Enum to Text property of TextBlock in ListBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am not successful at getting my DataTrigger to work for binding to enum.

Each line in the ListBox is 'S', just as in the default Setter

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BindToEnumTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindToEnumTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="LBMain" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="TxtType">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="S" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="TypeEnum.User">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="U"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace BindToEnumTest
{
    public enum TypeEnum { None, System, User }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Collection<TypeEnum> TypeList = new() { TypeEnum.System, TypeEnum.User, TypeEnum.System, TypeEnum.User };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LBMain.DataContext = TypeList;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using 'TypeEnum.User' and 'User' in the DataTrigger - no help.

 Using Text="{Binding}" in the TextBlock shows 'User' and 'System' in the ListBox, so it seems to be getting the data.

How can I change this trigger to function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TypeEnum` instance has no `Type` property, hence the Binding must not specify a property path:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Static local:TypeEnum.User}">
```

Or with built-in type conversion from string to enum:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="User">
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But in my building a Test program, I neglected to use a list for the data. I updated the original post to include the list

Comment: Please do not "neglect" important details. And do not make such modifications to your question after it has been answered. I have reverted your edit.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know the protocols. Do I post it as a new question with the changes?

Comment: You could do that, but if you have a collection of objects with a MyType property that holds the enum value, the correct Binding would obviously be `{Binding MyType}`. Be aware that the property needs to be public though.

Comment: I put that {Binding MyType}, but still just get S on each line.

Comment: The property needs to be public. You should have observed data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you run the application in debug mode.

Comment: Ah, such a simple solution! 'Public' was the problem with my original program this was written for. Thanks!